# Express: Accessing req.session from /models/index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've built a series of database queries in my express app that reside in a `/models/index.js` file which I can access from `app.js` via `var express = require('express');`. I am trying to populate `req.session.user` with a userid that is returned by a `findByEmail();` function in `/models/index.js`.

The `findByEmail();` function works fine, however I can't figure out how to store its return value in `req.session`. I've tried including `req.session.id = result.rows[0].id;` in the 'findByEmail();`function, but this returns a`req is not defined` error.

Am I overlooking a simple `require` statement in my `/models/index.js` file or is there another trick to accessing `req.session` in a module?

I've included the relevant code from `/models.index.js` below:

/models.index.js:

```
var pg = require('pg');

function findByEmail(email){
  pg.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('pg.connect error');
      throw err;
    }
    client.query('BEGIN', function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log('client.query BEGIN error');
        return rollback(client, done);
      }
      process.nextTick(function() {
        var text = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1";
        client.query(text, [email], function(err, result) {
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return rollback(client, done);
          }
          console.log(result);
          console.log(result.rows);
          console.log('id: ', result.rows[0].id);
          req.session.id = result.rows[0].id;
          done();
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
module.exports.pg = pg;
exports.findByEmail = findByEmail;
```

Comment: You must separate concerns, call `findByEmail` in the request and then set the session data in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as `/models/index.js` knows, `req` is not defined, same thing with `rollback`. A module is a closure and you don't have access to variables defined outside of it.
If you want to do that you must pass them as parameters but it's not very good design, as @gustavohenke said: Separation of concerns.
You might want to have a callback and call it with success/error and set the session id there so you don't have to pass in into the module:

```
function findByEmail(email,callback){
  pg.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('pg.connect error');
      throw err;
    }
        // Do all the async work and when you are done ...
        // An error is usually passed as the first parameter of the callback
        callback(err,result)
  });
}
exports.findByEmail = findByEmail;
```

You would then call it like this:

```
var models = require('./models');

models.findByEmail('thedude@lebowski.com',function(err,results) {
  // set session id here where you probably have access to the req object...
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this enabled me to figure it out. One additional note, I had to rename `req.session.id` in my original example to `req.session.userid` in the final working version because express would not accept the former (I presume `id` is a reserved name).

Comment: Does it throw an exception?